# Trying to display date in different way

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to display the date , as for exemple "yesterday at 21:00" , I'm trying to select just the DataTime values from sqlite , but I cannot figure this out here is my code

```
  public Cursor getDate(Product produit){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("select strftime('%H:%M', created_at) as created_at from " + TABLE_PRODUCT, null);
        return res;
    }
```

Comment: can you give us more details about your issue like the table structure, the output of this methode ... ?

Comment: @RidaeHAMDANI the issue I want to display in my application a date like for example "yesterday at the time " where the time for example = 5pm , I displayed the day but not in the way that I want , just in this format "20-12-2019" I want to translat this to yesterday , last week last month ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming** that your dates are stored in a recognised format [**see Date And Time Functions - Time Strings**](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) then you could use something like :-

```
WITH 
    /* Common Table Expression (CTE) to produce :-
        get the rowid for joining data back to product table
        the time difference in seconds
        the time in AM/PM
        and to pass the created_at column to the next CTE
    */
    times(rowid,timediff,timeasampm,created_at) AS 
    (
        SELECT rowid,
            strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s',created_at),
            CASE 
                WHEN CAST(strftime('%H',created_at) AS INTEGER) < 13 THEN strftime('%H:%M',created_at)||' AM'
                ELSE strftime('%H:%M',created_at,'-12 hours')||' PM'
            END,
            created_at
        FROM product AS p
    ),
    /* CTE to produce :-
        a user friendly textual representation of the date  
    */
    periods(rowid,period) AS
    (
        SELECT rowid,
        CASE
            WHEN timediff < 0 THEN 'created in the future!!!!' 
            /* Today */
            WHEN timediff < (60 * 60 * 24) 
                THEN ' today at '||timeasampm
            /* Yesterday */
            WHEN timediff < ((60 * 60 * 24) * 2) 
                THEN ' yesterday at '||timeasampm
            /* this week */
            WHEN timediff < ((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) 
                THEN  CAST(timediff / (60 * 60 * 24) AS TEXT)||' days ago at '||timeasampm
            /* Last Week */
            WHEN timediff < (((60 * 60 * 24) * 7)) 
                THEN ' last week'
            /* 1 Week ago but less than 2 weeks ago */
            WHEN timediff < (((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) * 4) 
                AND timediff / ((60 * 60 * 24) * 7)  = 1 
                THEN CAST(timediff / ((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) AS INTEGER)||' week ago on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm
            /* x weeks ago and in the current month  */
            WHEN timediff < (((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) * 4) 
                AND strftime('%m',created_at) = strftime('%m','now') 
                THEN CAST(timediff / ((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) AS INTEGER)||' weeks ago on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm
            /* Last month  and in the same year */
            WHEN strftime('%m',created_at) <> strftime('%m','now') 
                AND strftime('%Y',created_at) = strftime('%Y','now') 
                AND strftime('%m','now') - strftime('%m',created_at) = 1
                THEN 'last month on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm
            /* x Months ago if in the same year */
            WHEN strftime('%m',created_at) <> strftime('%m','now') 
                AND strftime('%Y',created_at) = strftime('%Y','now') 
                AND strftime('%m','now') - strftime('%m',created_at) > 1
                THEN CAST(strftime('%m','now') - strftime('%m',created_at) AS TEXT)||' months ago on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm
            /* Last year */
            WHEN strftime('%Y','now') - strftime('%Y',created_at) = 1
                THEN 'last year on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm
            /* if none of the above then x Years ago */
            ELSE CAST(strftime('%Y','now') - strftime('%Y',created_at) AS TEXT)||' years ago on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm
        END AS period
        FROM times
    )
SELECT product.*, periods.period FROM product 
    JOIN periods ON product.rowid = periods.rowid
;
```

This placed into your `getDate` method could be :-

```
public Cursor getDate(Product produit){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("WITH times(rowid,timediff,timeasampm,created_at) AS (SELECT rowid,strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s',created_at),CASE WHEN CAST(strftime('%H',created_at) AS INTEGER) < 13 THEN strftime('%H:%M',created_at)||' AM' ELSE strftime('%H:%M',created_at,'-12 hours')||' PM' END,created_at FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCT + "),periods(rowid,period) AS(SELECT rowid,CASE WHEN timediff < 0 THEN 'created in the future!!!!' WHEN timediff < (60 * 60 * 24) THEN ' today at '||timeasampm WHEN timediff < ((60 * 60 * 24) * 2) THEN ' yesterday at '||timeasampm WHEN timediff < ((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) THEN  CAST(timediff / (60 * 60 * 24) AS TEXT)||' days ago at '||timeasampm WHEN timediff < (((60 * 60 * 24) * 7)) THEN ' last week' WHEN timediff < (((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) * 4) AND timediff / ((60 * 60 * 24) * 7)  = 1 THEN CAST(timediff / ((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) AS INTEGER)||' week ago on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm WHEN timediff < (((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) * 4) AND strftime('%m',created_at) = strftime('%m','now') THEN CAST(timediff / ((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) AS INTEGER)||' weeks ago on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm WHEN strftime('%m',created_at) <> strftime('%m','now') AND strftime('%Y',created_at) = strftime('%Y','now') AND strftime('%m','now') - strftime('%m',created_at) = 1 THEN 'last month on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm WHEN strftime('%m',created_at) <> strftime('%m','now') AND strftime('%Y',created_at) = strftime('%Y','now') AND strftime('%m','now') - strftime('%m',created_at) > 1 THEN CAST(strftime('%m','now') - strftime('%m',created_at) AS TEXT)||' months ago on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm WHEN strftime('%Y','now') - strftime('%Y',created_at) = 1 THEN 'last year on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm ELSE CAST(strftime('%Y','now') - strftime('%Y',created_at) AS TEXT)||' years ago on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm END AS period FROM times) SELECT product.*, periods.period FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCT + " JOIN periods ON product.rowid = periods.rowid; ", null);
}
```

## Demo

- Note this includes a simpler example
- See comments
- Unlike java's Switch a matched WHEN clause infers a BREAK i.e. when met then that option is taken and subsequent WHEN or ELSE clause are effectively no-ops. This is intrinsic to the query.

Using :-

```
/* Create test environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS product (created_at);

/* LOad some testing data */
INSERT INTO product VALUES
    (datetime('now','-10 hours')),
    (datetime('now','-5 days')),
    (datetime('now','-1 days')),
    (datetime('now','-10 days')),
    (datetime('now','-20 days')),
    (datetime('now','-1 months')),
    (datetime('now','-2 months')),
    (datetime('now','-1 years')),
    (datetime('now','-3 years')),
    (datetime('now','-11 minutes')),
    (datetime('now','-10 seconds')),
    (datetime('now','+2 minutes')),
    (datetime('now','+2 years'))
    ;

SELECT *, datetime('now'), strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s',created_at) FROM product;

SELECT created_at,
    CASE 
        WHEN strftime('%Y','now') - strftime('%Y',created_at) > 0 THEN CAST(strftime('%Y','now') - strftime('%Y',created_at) AS TEXT)||' years ago'
        WHEN strftime('%m','now') - strftime('%m',created_at) > 0 THEN CAST(strftime('%m','now') - strftime('%m',created_at) AS TEXT)||' months ago'

        WHEN strftime('%d','now') - strftime('%d',created_at) = 1 THEN CAST(strftime('%d','now') - strftime('%d',created_at) AS TEXT)
        ||' yesterday at ' || CASE WHEN strftime('%H',created_at) < '13' THEN CAST(strftime('%H',created_at) AS TEXT)||' AM' ELSE CAST((strftime('%H',created_at) /*- 12*/) AS TEXT)|| ' PM' END
        WHEN strftime('%d','now') - strftime('%d',created_at) > 1 THEN CAST(strftime('%d','now') - strftime('%d',created_at) AS TEXT)||' days ago'
        WHEN strftime('%H','now') - strftime('%H',created_at) > 0 THEN CAST(strftime('%H','now') - strftime('%H',created_at) AS TEXT)||' hours ago'
        WHEN strftime('%M','now') - strftime('%M',created_at) > 0 THEN CAST(strftime('%M','now') - strftime('%M',created_at) AS TEXT)||' minutes ago'
        WHEN strftime('%S','now') - strftime('%S',created_at) > 0 THEN CAST(strftime('%S','now') - strftime('%S',created_at) AS TEXT)||' seconds ago'
        ELSE strftime(' just now')
    END AS ago
FROM product 
ORDER BY strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s',created_at); /* ORDER BY to make result easier to read */


WITH 
    /* Common Table Expression (CTE) to produce :-
        get the rowid for joining data back to product table
        the time difference in seconds
        the time in AM/PM
        and to pass the created_at column to the next CTE
    */
    times(rowid,timediff,timeasampm,created_at) AS 
    (
        SELECT rowid,
            strftime('%s','now') - strftime('%s',created_at),
            CASE 
                WHEN CAST(strftime('%H',created_at) AS INTEGER) < 13 THEN strftime('%H:%M',created_at)||' AM'
                ELSE strftime('%H:%M',created_at,'-12 hours')||' PM'
            END,
            created_at
        FROM product AS p
    ),
    /* CTE to produce :-
        a user friendly textual representation of the date in the past (assumes)    
    */
    periods(rowid,period) AS
    (
        SELECT rowid,
        CASE
            WHEN timediff < 0 THEN 'created in the future!!!!' 
            /* Today */
            WHEN timediff < (60 * 60 * 24) 
                THEN ' today at '||timeasampm
            /* Yesterday */
            WHEN timediff < ((60 * 60 * 24) * 2) 
                THEN ' yesterday at '||timeasampm
            /* this week */
            WHEN timediff < ((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) 
                THEN  CAST(timediff / (60 * 60 * 24) AS TEXT)||' days ago at '||timeasampm
            /* Last Week */
            WHEN timediff < (((60 * 60 * 24) * 7)) 
                THEN ' last week'
            /* 1 Week ago but less than 2 weeks ago */
            WHEN timediff < (((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) * 4) 
                AND timediff / ((60 * 60 * 24) * 7)  = 1 
                THEN CAST(timediff / ((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) AS INTEGER)||' week ago on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm
            /* x weeks ago and in the current month  */
            WHEN timediff < (((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) * 4) 
                AND strftime('%m',created_at) = strftime('%m','now') 
                THEN CAST(timediff / ((60 * 60 * 24) * 7) AS INTEGER)||' weeks ago on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm
            /* Last month  and in the same year */
            WHEN strftime('%m',created_at) <> strftime('%m','now') 
                AND strftime('%Y',created_at) = strftime('%Y','now') 
                AND strftime('%m','now') - strftime('%m',created_at) = 1
                THEN 'last month on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm
            /* x Months ago if in the same year */
            WHEN strftime('%m',created_at) <> strftime('%m','now') 
                AND strftime('%Y',created_at) = strftime('%Y','now') 
                AND strftime('%m','now') - strftime('%m',created_at) > 1
                THEN CAST(strftime('%m','now') - strftime('%m',created_at) AS TEXT)||' months ago on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm
            /* Last year */
            WHEN strftime('%Y','now') - strftime('%Y',created_at) = 1
                THEN 'last year on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm
            /* if none of the above then x Years ago */
            ELSE CAST(strftime('%Y','now') - strftime('%Y',created_at) AS TEXT)||' years ago on '||date(created_at)||' at '||timeasampm
        END AS period
        FROM times
    )
SELECT product.*, periods.period FROM product 
    JOIN periods ON product.rowid = periods.rowid
;

/* Cleanup Testing Environment */
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS product;
```

Results in

- Note highlighted rows indicate dates in the future

a) The loaded data :-

[image]

b) The *simpler query* :-

[image]

c) The more complex query as suggested :-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

## Problem :

In SQLite **strftime()** function is used to **convert given datetime string into defined format**. Not to figure out the passed time.

## Solution :

Instead of that you can use  'DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()' method from android.text.format.DateUtils class to figure out the passed time from given time.

## Example :

Here is an example

```
import android.text.format.DateUtils
...

fun timeDiff(date: String): CharSequence {
    val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.getDefault())
    var startDate = Date()
    simpleDateFormat.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")

    try {
        startDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(date)
    } catch (pe: ParseException) {
        pe.printStackTrace()
    }

    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
    calendar.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
    return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
        startDate.time,
        calendar.timeInMillis,
        DateUtils.SECOND_IN_MILLIS
    )
}
```

Or if you have time in long format

```
fun timeDiff(l: Long): CharSequence {
    val instance = Calendar.getInstance()
    instance.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")
    return DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(Date(l).time, instance.timeInMillis, 1000)
}
```